# Validação em tempo real de um textField

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Tenho uma aplicação em Swift 1 para iPAD, gostaria de remover ou não aceitar a entrada de "." no meu textField. Ele está como NumberPad. Encontrei algumas soluções aqui mas nenhuma em Swift.

Comment: [OFF] Curiosidade não relacionada a pergunta: Qual motivo de ainda estar utilizando Swift 1?

Answer (score 0):

Se voce ta precisando fazer um campo para entrada de números inteiros você pode simplesmente subclass UITextField e customizar o seu field dentro do método awakeFromNib e você também pode adicionar lá o addTarget para UIControlEvents .editingChanged e um método para filtrar os caracteres que não sejam dígitos. Segue o link da [reposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294660/2303865) que eu ja postei/atualizei no SO em ingles:

```
import UIKit

class IntegerField: UITextField {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        keyboardType = .numberPad
        textAlignment = .right
        editingChanged()
    }
    func editingChanged() {
        text = Formatter.decimal.string(from: string.numbers.integer as NSNumber)
    }
}

struct Formatter {
    static let decimal = NumberFormatter(numberStyle: .decimal)
}

extension UITextField {
    var string: String { return text ?? "" }
}

extension String {
    var numbers: String { return components(separatedBy: Numbers.characterSet.inverted).joined() }
    var integer: Int { return Int(numbers) ?? 0 }
}

struct Numbers { static let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789") }

extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(numberStyle: NumberFormatter.Style) {
        self.init()
        self.numberStyle = numberStyle
    }
}
```